# InfoPath Horizontal Repeating Table

Tags: infopath

How do you create Horizontal Repeating Tables in InfoPath 2013? I've found answers for 2010, but none of the solutions work in 2013

Answer (score 0):

Check your form's compatibility. You can set a repeating section (under the section's properties) to repeat horizontally in InfoPath 2010 or 2013, but only if you are using a filler form.

Comment: Can you expand on what a filler form is? Can you do this with a web-based form?

Comment: A Filler Form is a template meant to be filled out InfoPath Filler. So, no, I'm afraid this is not possible in a browser (web-based) form - the option just isn't there in the control properties.